# How to use a SolidColorBrush in GradientStop?

Tags: xaml, colors

We have this standard color in our application:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ThemeColor" Color="#FF95BBF0"/>
```

We are trying to use it as a GradientStop but get a type-mismatch error:

```
<GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ThemeColor}" Offset="1" />
```

What is the syntax to convert this in XAML, something like this:

**PSEUDO-CODE:**

```
<GradientStop SolidColorBrush="{DynamicResource ThemeColor}" Offset="1" />
<GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ThemeColor}.Color" Offset="1" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define `ThemeColor` as `Color`

```
<Color x:Key="ThemeColor" >#FF95BBF0</Color>
```

because this is what `GradientStop` expects